# Check if url contains string with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have a page with select options and I am using JQuery to refresh the page and add a string to the url when an option is clicked.  Now I need a way to check the browsers url to see if it contains said string.

Looking on other threads I thought `indexOf` would work, but when trying this it doesn't work.  How else would I check if the URL contains something like `?added-to-cart=555`? The complete URL would normally look like: `http://my-site.com`, and after clicking one of the options it looks like this after page reload: `http://my-site.com/?added-to-cart=555`.  I just need to check to see if the URL contains that `?added-to-cart=555` bit.

Here is what I have:

```
jQuery("#landing-select option").click(function(){

 $('#product-form').submit();

    window.location.href += $(this).val()

});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
if(window.location.indexOf("?added-to-cart=555") >= 0)
            {
                 alert("found it");
            }
});
```

Comment: Didn't you notice the error `TypeError: window.location.indexOf is not a function` in the console? [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging). Reading the [MDN documentation about `window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location) is helpful as well.

Comment: Update to `window.location.href.indexOf("string-to-match")`

Answer (score 99, accepted):

> Use Window.location.href to take the url in javascript.  it's a
>   property that will tell you the current URL location of the browser.
>   Setting the property to something different will redirect the page.

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("?added-to-cart=555") > -1) {
    alert("found it");
}
```

Comment: It may be helpful to explain what " > -1" does in this scenario... it looks like adding this just checks whether or not this string exists in the window href. is there a different way to solve this?

Comment: @john_h Yes, In the javascript indexOf method returns the position of the string. If the search string is avaliable it returns greater than or equal to zero(>=0). if it is not available it just returns -1 always.

Answer (score 10):

[window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location) is an object, not a string so you need to use window.location.href to get the actual string url

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("?added-to-cart=555") >= 0) {
    alert("found it");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use `href` with `indexof`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
   if(window.location.href.indexOf("added-to-cart=555") > -1) {
   alert("your url contains the added-to-cart=555");
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("?added-to-cart=555") >= 0)
```

It's `window.location.href`, not `window.location`.