# Smooth Anchor Scroll with url

Tags: jquery, scroll

I want to achieve smooth scrolling to an anchor with jQuery. I found some solutions, however, they're all based on the fact that the link to the anchor looks like this:

```
<a href="#anchor-id">TEST</a>
```

In my scenario, the links look like this:

```
<a href="some-page#anchor-id">TEST</a>
```

I have a global navigation-bar that has the link to "some-page" and hovering the menu-entry opens a dropdown inlcuding the links to the anchors on that page.

I found the following script online which works for regular anchor links `<a href="#...">`:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var target = this.hash,
   $target = $(target);

   $('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $taeget.offset().top-60 
   }, 4000, 'swing', function () {
      window.location.hash = target;
   });
});
```

The link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2nT8M/5/

The fiddle doesn't seem to work, however the code does work on my website...

**My questions:**

- How can I get the script to work in the fiddle (obviously)?
- Is it possible to use links that include more than just the anchor ID, as needed in my scenario?

Comment: what exactly isnt working? if I click your TEST anchor it scrolls down to the ANCHOR element just as expected in the fiddle.. besides you got a typo in your $('a[href^="#"]' <- no closing bracket

Comment: Thanks, the typo broke the code in the fiddle...now it is working. However, if I use the script with this type of link `<a href="sample-page#anchor">`it is not working. It only works with #anchor... how can I get it to work with the longer links?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2nT8M/6/ this is just a smooth scroll example for the short links. for the longer ones you have to get the #anchor-id from your href like this for example: var target = $( $(this).attr('href') ); after that: target = '#' + target.split('#')[1]

Comment: Hey, can you write it as code please? I don't get it where what belongs...

Answer (score 0):

This is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2nT8M/7/

if you want to scroll to an element with an id equal to the #-part for your anchor you can access it like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="one"><a class="link" href="da#test">TEST</a></div>
<a id="test">ANCHOR</a>
<div id="two"><a class="link" href="ws#test2">TEST2</a></div>
<a id="test2">ANCHOR</a>
```

Just give an element (in this case ANCHOR) the same ID as your #-part for your href. Also give all clickable anachors a class="link" e.g.

If you check my fiddle you see the following JS:

```
$('.link').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var target = $(this).attr('href');
  target = $('#' + target.split('#')[1]);
  if( target.length ) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

like this its getting the #-Part of every anchor you click and scroll to the element with the same ID.

Some details:

```
target.split('#')[1]
```

This part takes the href string saved in target before and splits it in 2 parts at '#'. the first part for the first anchor is 'da' and the 2nd part is 'test'. You want 'test' therefor you access it with [1] (its an array).

Now all whats left to do is put a '#' in front of it and use it as a selector:

```
target = $('#' + target.split('#')[1]);
```

$('#test') is now your target you want to scroll to.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the explanation. There is a big problem: the script breaks my navigation. My navbar has links to 5 pages, on hover they reveal drop downs and these include links like `<a href="/sample-page/#test">`. If I am on that page, the scrolling works, but if I want to go to another page the top-level links don't work...

Comment: Ok, I changed the link-class, actually my html-structure is `<ul class="sub-menu"><li><a ...>` so I changed your `$('.link')` to `$('.sub-menu a')`. My navigation works again, but I can't open any of the `<a href="/sample-page/#test">`links if I am not on that sample-page

Comment: Ok, I specified the link-class a little more: If you're on SAMPLE-PAGE the smooth scrolling works and the rest of the navbar too. If you're not on SAMPLE-PAGE all links work, but if you try to open `<a href="/sample-page/#test">` you only get to the top of SAMPLE-PAGE. The ideal behavior would be: if you're not on the designated page jump directly to the anchor. If you're on that page already, smoothly scroll to the anchor... do you know how to detect that?

Comment: well, event.preventDefault prevent's the anchor element from redirecting. you could put an if statement inside the function. like if the current url contains your sample-page put all the code of the function in (including prevent default) else you could do someting like return true - since there is no preventdefault it will just follow the anchor link and would redirect to the site you want to

Comment: an example how to detect a part of the url could be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718282/check-if-url-contains-string-with-jquery